# A convex relaxation for surface volume calculated using divergence theorem: Is this integral convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, exterior-algebra

This question is related to the following:
[Prove/disprove convexity of surface volume in terms of a deformation field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4151405/685910) - the context is summarized below for clarity.

In the setting of convex optimization, I am looking for a convex relaxation of a potential $U=pV$ of a scalar pressure $p$ acting over some volume $V$ enclosed by a parametric surface embedded in a Cartesian frame. Hence I need a convex relaxation of $V$.

Consider the following functions:
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{X}(\xi^1, \xi^2)\\
\\
\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}(\xi^1, \xi^2)\\
\\
(\xi^1, \xi^2) \in  \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \mathbf{X,u} \in \mathbb{R}^3\\
\end{split}
$$

Here $\mathbf{X}$ are the coordinates of a point on the undeformed surface $S$ and $\mathbf{u}$ is the deformation field, such that, using convected coordinates, the position of the original point on the deformed surface $s$ is given by $\mathbf{x=X+u}$.

The enclosed volume $V$ of $s$ can now be defined by application of the divergence theorem by integrating a function of unit divergence:
$$
\begin{split}
V=\frac{1}{3}\int{\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{n}} da
\end{split}.
$$

As shown in my related question, this integral can be written as:
$$
\begin{split}
V = \frac{1}{3}\int{  \mathbf{x} \cdot \left((\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \xi^1} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \xi^1}) \times (\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \xi^2} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \xi^2}) \right)}  d\xi^1d\xi^2
\end{split}.
$$
In the above, the vector cross product represents the (outward oriented) non-unit normal to the deformed surface $s$, which is the cross product of the tangent vectors on $s$, say $\mathbf{g_1}$ and $\mathbf{g_2}$. Thus $V$ can be interpreted as the sum of the volumes of differential pyramids of height $\mathbf{x}$ and (oriented) differential base area $(\mathbf{g_1 \times g_2})  d\xi^1d\xi^2$.

Now assuming the origin is always 'inside' the surface, each differential pyramid should always have positive volume, which leads me to believe the following is a suitable convex relaxation of $V$:

$$
\begin{split}
U = pV = p\int _V dV = \frac{p}{3}\int \left| (\mathbf{X+u}) \cdot \left[\bigg(\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \xi^1} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \xi^1}\bigg) \times \bigg(\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \xi^2} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \xi^2}\bigg) \right] \right| d\xi^1d\xi^2
\end{split}
$$

Is the above integral always convex in $\mathbf{u}$ for a fixed $\mathbf{X}$, or are further restrictions needed? Does the surface itself need to be convex?

Comment: Surely a constant is convex in general?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345778/proof-composition-of-analytic-functions-is-analytic): in particular, give definitions.

Comment: I have edited the question and provided context and more detail. Note this question is related to my other question math.stackexchange.com/q/4151405/685910 - should I have instead modified that question instead? @TobyMak

Comment: @copper.hat It should be clear now that only $X$ is constant

Comment: @olekn Much better, thanks for making the changes.